# Regular Expression without the use of ^ and $ operators?

Tags: regex, compiler-construction

I have an regex ^[^aeiou]*$ which matches any lines that does not contain a lowercase vowel. I have an assignment where I have to make an expression that does the same job without using ^ and $. Is it possible?

I thought about this one [b-df-hj-np-tv-z]* but it if I enter the word usa it breaks it down and accepts the letter s.

This question is in compiler design dragon book[image]

Comment: The short answer to the assignment is no.

Comment: Since this is homework, I will only offer some hints. Investigate `\A`, `\Z` and lookahead assertions.

Comment: I tried \A [b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*\Z but it does not work in FLEX. Same result. Lookahead assertions are also not supported by flex. I have to submit it tomorrow but nothing seems to work